# CSV to JSON issue using python

Tags: python, json, csv

```
import csv
import json
csv_file = 'data.csv'
json_path = 'data.json'

data1 = {}

with open(csv_file) as data_csv:
    csvRead = csv.DictReader(data_csv)
    for csvrows in csvRead:
        id = csvrows['row_id']
        data[id] = csvrows

# Creating Multiple JSON files of 1000 rows each
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    data_file = dict(list(data.items())[j:j+1000])
    with open(json_path + "data" + str(j) + ".json", 'w') as data_json:
        data_json.write(json.dumps(data1, indent=4))
    i = i + 1000
```

The problem is I get output as

```
[ "1": { "id": 1, "name": "Smitraj", "Lastname":"Raut" } ]
```

But I don't want it in this format.
I need the format as

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "Smitraj", "Lastname":"Raut" } ]
```

Comment: The JSON you have posted is invalid and not the result of the code given.

Comment: could you show your csv file pl..?

Comment: The second json is not valid. It's easy to modify your code to output like: { "1": {"name": "Smitraj","Lastname": "Raut"}}. Would that be ok?

Comment: I want this format[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Smitraj",
    "Lastname":"Raut"
  } ]  but what I get is extra index in the start   [ "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Smitraj",
    "Lastname":"Raut"

Comment: The output you say you get cannot result from this code and is not valid JSON. The code contains a variable `data1` which is not related to anything else in here, but that could not produce the output you claim you get, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Instead of a dictionary append you items to a list and write that to file.

```
import csv
import json
csv_file = 'data.csv'
json_path = 'data.json'

data = []

with open(csv_file) as data_csv:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(data_csv)
    for csvrows in csv_reader:
        data.append(csvrows)

with open(json_path, 'w') as data_json:
    data_json.write(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

Comment: Thanks I have done the same code for the per 1000 rows... Thanks for you contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import json

csv_path = 'D:/test/data.csv'
json_path = 'D:/test/'

x=[]

with open(csv_path) as data_csv:
    data_csvRead = csv.DictReader(data_csv)
    for data_csvrows in data_csvRead:
        x.append(data_csvrows)

len(x)


j=0
while j<len(x):
    data = x[j:j+1000]
    with open(json_path+"data_file"+str(j)+".json", 'w') as datarument_json:
        datarument_json.write(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
    j=j+1000
```